# Integrate a function with pandas and scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to integrate a function with pandas and scipy in the most elegant way possible, but I'm getting the following error when executing:

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

This is a preview of the data set:

```
           0       1    Live  time:  11646
0        1.0     2.0     0.0    0.0    0.0
1        2.0     3.0     0.0    0.0    0.0
2        3.0     4.0     0.0    0.0    0.0
3        4.0     5.0     1.0    0.0    0.0
4        5.0     6.0     2.0    0.0    0.0
...      ...     ...     ...    ...    ...
4094  4095.0  4096.0  4092.0    1.0    0.0
4095  4096.0  4097.0  4093.0    0.0    0.0
4096  4097.0  4098.0  4094.0    1.0    0.0
4097  4098.0  4099.0  4095.0    2.0    0.0
4098  4099.0  4100.0  4096.0    0.0    0.0
```

I know there are other ways to solve the problem, but I would like to keep the lambda function, because it makes things simpler.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

dados = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',| |\t|\s+', engine='python')
dados = dados.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype('float')

def func(x):
    return x[3]/x[3].max()

dados['I'] = dados.apply(lambda x: quad(func, 140.0, 4000.0), axis=1)
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to do in the func?

Comment: divide the values ​​of the fourth column of the dataframe by their maximum value

Comment: `func(x)` is getting the integration variable passed to it by `quad`.  You aren't doing anything with the `x` variable of the `lambda` (which will be a `Series`, a row of `dados`).  Rewrite the `lambda` to be a function, and include a `print(x)`.  The do the same for `func`.  That way you can figure out what value(s) is being passed at each stage.  It might also help to get the `quad` call working correctly for an array (or scalar parameter).  `quad` is a numpy/scipy function.

Comment: print(type(x[3])) returns a numpy.float64 type, in both cases